# Error after signing up with Devise on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have simple Rails 4 app with Devise gem - I have simple authentication with email confirmation. 
Local everything works perfect.
On Heroku when I try sign up and fill in form with invalid data it's still fine.
Problem appears only when I fill in sign up form with correct data and I submit it.

I get `"We're sorry, but something went wrong".`

My route file:

```
devise_for :users
root to: 'home#index'
match '/user_page', to: 'user_page#index', via: :all
```

Heroku logs:

```
2014-07-10T17:53:37.267324+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-10T17:53:37.258566+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-10T17:53:37.258590+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to aa@aaaa.pl (15.7ms)
2014-07-10T17:53:37.260881+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 529ms
```

So it send email and after that crash.

Have you got any ideas? What should I check?

Comment: how is mail getting delivered?

Comment: my mistake. it isn't of course

Comment: Take a look at [Mandrill for Heroku add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/mandrill). This is scalable email delivery with analytics for applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the error occurs when Heroku attempts to send the email (upon successful user registration).

I assume your app is using an "email" add-on such as SendGrid on Heroku. Have you configured your `action_mailer.default_url_options` in `production.rb` environment file?

Per the [Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise):

Next, you need to set up the default URL options for the Devise mailer in each environment. Here is a possible configuration for `config/environments/development.rb`:

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }`

Just make sure to use your app's actual domain for the host key in `production.rb`.

Comment: thank you! i forgot about change its line in my production.rb. now it seems to by ok - redirected correct after sign up